# QTcpServer->listen() on WinCE6 "protocol type not supported"

Tags: c++, qt, windows-ce, qtcpserver

I made an application which has to run on a Win32 as well as WinCE6 (x86) machine. It works perfectly on Win32 but when it executes on a WinCE6 machine:

```
m_TcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1024)
```

it returns false and says: "protocol type not supported"

I already googled it but I couln´t find any solution for this problem and I would really appreciate it, if somebody could help me with this.

Thanks,
Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` instead. Its probably trying to bind to an IPv6 interface which won't work on WinCE.